# How to make pagination through a SharePoint 2013 list view with GetItems and GetItemsInFolder?

Tags: c#, pagination, sharepoint-2013, paging

I am developing a WCF service that retrieve items from SharePoint 2013 (Server Side Model), through views:

```
var list = web.Lists[someLibGuid];//Document Library List
var view = list.Views[0];
var folder = web.GetFolder(someFolderGuid);
var items = list.GetItems(view);
var itemsInFolder = ((SPDocumentLibrary)list).GetItemsInFolder(view, folder);
```

By default both GetItems and GetItemsInFolder will retrieve the default rowlimit(let's say 30 items)

How to get next page(next 30 items) through this specific view ?

Comment: what code do you have in wcf end

Comment: The code in the question is a snapshot of WCF one, i just need a way to get next or page X through a specific view